# After assiging SelectedValuePath to Comobox still it takes SelectedValue null when assigned

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, combobox

After assiging SelectedValuePath to Comobox still it takes SelectedValue null when assigned. The comboBox gets populated with data but when an id is assigned to SelectedValue it always returns null.

C#:

```
var fillDoctor = (from a in db.Persons
                           select new
                                  {
                                      id = a.id,
                                      name = a.name + " " + a.middle_name + " " + a.last_name
                                  });

                _cmbDoctor.ItemsSource = fillDoctor;
                _cmbDoctor.DisplayMemberPath = "name";//"first_name" + " " + "middle_name" + " " + "last_name";
                _cmbDoctor.SelectedValuePath = "id";

                _cmbDoctor.SelectedValue = 51;

MessageBox.Show(_cmbDoctor.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a person with ID 51? If there is no such ID then the combobox has nothing to point at

Comment: yes i am sure....i have the same code in two different form in one it works and in the second it returns null.

Comment: I once had similar issue. Try to assign the item source after assiging the selectedvaluepath and displaymember path